# Interfaces are strong or weak reference?

Tags: java, android, oop

I compose this question with example using Android terminology, but I think it remains same for all object oriented programming.

If there are two fragments (class) with name `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` and an interface with name `Interface1`

`FragmentA` implements the interface 'Interface1'.

`FragmentA` creates object of `FragmentB` and store it as a strong reference instance variable.

`FragmentA` also passes `this` (implementation of `Interface1`) to `FragmentB`'s constructor as part of object creation.

`FragmentB` stores the `Interface1` implementation object (in this case `FragmentA`'s object) as a strong reference instance variable called `mInterface1Obj`.

1- Does `mInterface1Obj` of `FragmentB` hold strong reference to `FragmentA` object?

2- Does Memory leak occur on this scenario?

3- Should `mInterface1Obj` be a weak reference (`WeakReference<Interface1> mInterface1Obj` instead of `Interface1 mInterface1Obj`) to avoid memory leak?

Comment: You're confusing completely unrelated concepts. Interfaces have nothing to do with reference strength or memory leaks. And there's no inherent memory leak in your scenario, unless objects are referenced unnecessarily.

Comment: What the asker would like to know is whether there is an issue of circular references here which would prevent the GC from disposing of either of the fragments. Clearly this would be the case if Fragment A references Fragment B and vice versa, but I would also like to know whether a circular reference exists when using an interface to the class as one of the references. Nobody seems to have answered that.

Answer (score -2):

> Does mInterface1Obj of FragmentB hold a strong reference to FragmentA object?

Yes. Until and unless you keep the reference in WeakReference object till that it will always keep the strong reference.

> Does Memory leak occur in this scenario?

It depends, for example in your fragment stack, if you remove Fragment1 from stack and Fragment2 will remain in the stack in such case memory leak will happen as Fragment2 is holding a strong reference of Fragment1.

> Should mInterface1Obj be a weak reference (WeakReference mInterface1Obj instead of Interface1 mInterface1Obj) to avoid memory leak?

That is the right way.

Comment: I think you want to work the formatting of your answer... This is very hard to read like this.

Comment: Besides the formatting, the answer itself is wrong. Whether a memory leak occurs depends on a whole lot of things besides just the stack navigation. And keeping a weak reference is not automatically the correct thing to do.

Comment: @LewBloch you are right it depends on lots of things, but here I pick a single example, are you want to say in provided example memory leaks won't happen?

Comment: @GhostCat I tried to make it more readable, hope now it is helpfull.

Comment: A lingering reference is not by definition a memory leak. Also, objects live on the heap, not the stack, and they can't be "removed".

Comment: Hi @Avi i am currently using the weakreference as shown in the question. In a scenario the parent fragment is removed and added again. Then my weakreference in the child fragment is getting garbage collected. How should such a case be handled?